# Unable to get value of the property 'toLowerCase', JQUERY 1.10.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, lowercase

I am using jquery 1.10.2.  I am trying to get the following piece of code to work:

```
$("[id*='value_']").val($(this).val());
```

I know as written the code will just set the value to whatever is currently in the tag.
But this is as far as I can go until I get rid of the error:

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; Tablet PC 2.0)
Timestamp: Mon, 10 Feb 2014 15:51:01 UTC


Message: Unable to get value of the property 'toLowerCase': object is null or undefined
Line: 5
Char: 6176
Code: 0
URI: https://ox-kkent11.fncinc.com/wssp/js_files/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
```

For instance:

```
$("[id*='value_']").val(2);
```

successfully writes a '2' in all fields that have an id that begins with "value_".

I intend to take the value of the field and convert it to currency.  But get the error before I can even try that.

Any pointers.  Plus if anyone knows of a more efficient way to turn all numbers (int and float) to currency with a '$', please tell me.

Comment: please show some code and what have you tried ?

Comment: What is the value of `this`? What's the context for that single line of code?

Comment: What is the `this` object you are referring to?

Comment: I use $(this).val() with the understanding that it will give me the current val of the element that "$("[id*='value_']")" obtains.

Comment: Maybe I am using $(this).val() incorrectly?

Comment: @Mildfire no, that's not what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a "$" to the value of some elements, it would look like this:

```
$("[id*='value_']").each(function() {
  $(this).val( "$" + $(this).val() );
});
```

Comment: i just thought about this.  I will let you know if it works.  THank you

Comment: this is what i ended up doing if anyone was curious: $("[id*='value_']").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val().indexOf(".") < 0) {
                    $(this).val($(this).val() + '.00');
                }
                if ($(this).val().indexOf("$") < 0) {
                    $(this).val("$" + $(this).val());
                }
            });